# Leaflet Browser Print - How to add image into the header of the print result?

Tags: dictionary, printing, leaflet

I am trying to print the map with a header that includes a text between two images, but i am not getting the right way to do this.

```
L.control.browserPrint({
        title: '...',
        documentTitle: '...',
        printModes: [
            L.BrowserPrint.Mode.Auto("A4", { title: "Auto", **header:{ enabled: true, text: 'Webmap - Braganca Paulista', size: "25mm", overTheMap: false, backgroundColo:'#f0f' }** }),
        ],
    }).addTo(map);
```

I've tried to call after using the class 'leaflet-browser-print-content' in the images, but it puts the images below the map. The header doens't has an default option to include images.